# Origin null is not allowed by access-control-allow-origin on Chrome

Tags: file, google-chrome

I'm developing a website to be used from a DVD, so I cannot rely on `http://` protocol. The HTML pages use jQuery and knockout.js and load data from the JSON file using `$.getJSON`.

This runs fine on Firefox but I get an `origin null is not allowed by access-control-allow-origin` on Chrome. I've looked many SO answers on this but I cannot force the users to start Chrome using additional command line parameters or putting the site on HTTP web server.

Is there a way to let Chrome open local files?

Answer (score 0):

I know this might be late, but I in the mist of a similiar problem. I have a solution for JSON (which I will share), but not for XML.

My solution was to use a javascript loader (ex: HeadJS) which does a great job for an application needing to run offline. I would create a file with .js in this manner.

```
var JSON = {
    Field1: "Text",
    Field2: "Text2"
}
```

Then I would use the loader. We actually allowed the user to choose which data they wanted and loaded that particular file.

Hope this help someone else.